How to run server side middleware before a Blazor WASM app loads
In our Blazor WASM app, I'm attempting to run custom middleware before the Blazor app initial loads. Basically I want to do some server side checks before the app loads, and if it doesn't pass those tests I want to throw a 404. I can't filter for / because I want this to run if somebody deep links to a page.
I'm able to get close to what I need by using this:
        app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            if (!CheckIfClientExists(ctx))
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });

However, I don't want to run this same code on every single HTTP request; only the initial request to load the SPA. If I were manually rendering a SPA, this would be easy to add to the Index action.

Your code seems correct there is no issue in it. and for initial load there is only / or the index file which is root url of the
so you could use:
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
   {
       // Check if the request is for the root or index.html (initial load)
       if (ctx.Request.Path == "/" || ctx.Request.Path == "/index.html")
       {
           if (!CheckIfClientExists(ctx))
           {
               ctx.Response.StatusCode = 404;
               return; // Stop further processing if check fails
           }
       }

       // Continue processing for other requests
       await next();
   });

And for function for example i have set the code to check the header you can use based on your requirement:
// Example server-side check function
   bool CheckIfClientExists(HttpContext ctx)
   {
              return ctx.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Client-Id");
   }

